# MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException on JSON webservice using GenericType

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

I have an issue reading a GenericType on my webservice client.

**Here is my webservice :**

```
    @GET
@Path("/results")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getPlayerResults(@QueryParam("nick") String nick, @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response) {

    // if (!isAuth(request, response)) {
    // authError(response);
    // }

    System.out.println(nick);
    GenericEntity<List<JSONTournament>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<JSONTournament>>(
            MongoTournaments.getPlayerResults(nick, null)) {
    };

    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

**My client :**

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/WS").path("players/results");

        Response response = webTarget.queryParam("nick", nick).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

        System.out.println(nick);   

        tournaments = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<JSONTournament>>() {
        });
```

**And I get this Exception and a strange media-type (text/html) instead of application/json... :**

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8, type=interface java.util.List, genericType=java.util.List<com.winascrap.database.model.JSONTournament>.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:812)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:368)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$2.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:119)
```

I don't understand what is missing or not done correctly.
My objects have @XmlRootElement annotations, I use jersey.core, jersey.media, and moxy as dependencies... (but maybe I forgot on dependencie or configuration ?) :

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

I missed to add an empty constructor to my custom type annoted with @XmlRootElement . It's working only adding a constructor without params.